# Update cart by removing duplicate entries in provider class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am working with a shopping cart app and using flutter-Provider to update my cart. Everything is working good but I am getting duplicate items in my cart list, How can I remove these duplicate entries and add quantities. I want to get the list with the items and quantities. Please help me with this piece of code that where can I add the logic and filter the list with removed duplicate items.

Here is my Code:

CartList.dart:

```
class CartList extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<CategoryItems> cartList = [];
  double _totalPrice = 0.0;

  addCartItem(CategoryItems categoryItems){
    cartList.add(categoryItems);
    categoryItems.Counter++;
    _totalPrice+=double.parse(categoryItems.OurPrice);
    notifyListeners();

  }



  removeCartItem(CategoryItems categoryItems){
    _totalPrice-=double.parse(categoryItems.OurPrice);
    categoryItems.Counter--;
    if(categoryItems.Counter<1){
      categoryItems.ShouldVisible = false;
    }

    cartList.remove(categoryItems);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get count{
    return cartList.length;

  }

  double get totalPrice{
    return _totalPrice;
  }



  List<CategoryItems> get basketItem{
    return cartList;
  }

  incrementCounter(CategoryItems categoryItems){
    categoryItems.Counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  decrementCounter(CategoryItems categoryItems)
  {
    categoryItems.Counter--;
    notifyListeners();
  }



}
```

CategoryItem.dart:

```
class CategoryItems{
  String CategoryName;
  int Counter;
  String MarketPrice;
  String Name;
  String OurPrice;
  bool ShouldVisible;
  String TotalDiscount;
  String Weight;
  int ID;

  String get getCategoryName => CategoryName;
  int get getCounter => Counter;
  String get getMarketPrice => MarketPrice;
  String get getName => Name;
  String get getOurPrice => OurPrice;
  bool get getShouldVisible => ShouldVisible;
  String get getTotalDiscount => TotalDiscount;
  String get getWeight => Weight;
  int get getID => ID;

  CategoryItems(
      this.CategoryName,
      this.Counter,
      this.MarketPrice,
      this.Name,
      this.OurPrice,
      this.ShouldVisible,
      this.TotalDiscount,
      this.Weight,
      this.ID
      );

}
```

Here I used Contain:

```
  addCartItem(CategoryItems categoryItems){
     if(cartList.contains(categoryItems.ID)){
       categoryItems.Counter++;
       _totalPrice+=double.parse(categoryItems.OurPrice);
     }else{
    cartList.add(categoryItems);
    categoryItems.Counter++;
    _totalPrice+=double.parse(categoryItems.OurPrice);
    notifyListeners();}

  }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using [List.contains](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/contains.html) before adding an item to your cart?

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work. Even I've defined product ID for each products but not able to achieve what I want.

Comment: Your code does not have any reference to contains.... What are you seeing when debugging the code when you use contains? Does it return true/false? If you are creating different objects each time, they will not be the same even if they hold the same value.

Comment: Product ID is my reference,  I will update Model as well

Comment: @tomerpacific, I'm also adding code where I've used Contain.

Comment: @tomerpacific, Do you want to suggest anything?

Comment: CartList contains objects of category items, so you cannot ask if it contains only the id. If it only held the ids, then that would yield the result you want. Another option would be to iterate over the list, checking to see if you have a match between an object in the list and the one you want to insert.

Answer (score 0):

I Iterate the Cart bucket and check for redundant value in ontap This way:

```
                                                                      bool itemFound = false;
                                                                      for(var i=0;i<CART.count;i++)
                                                                        {
                                                                         if(CART.count>=1 && categoryItemList[index].ID==CART.basketItem[i].ID){
                                                                           itemFound = true;
                                                                           break;
                                                                         }else{
                                                                           print('Item Not Exists');
                                                                         }
                                                                        }
                                                                      if(itemFound == true){
                                                                        print(itemFound);
                                                                        CART.addQuantityOnly(categoryItemList[index]);
                                                                      }else{
                                                                        print(itemFound);
                                                                        CART.addCartItem(categoryItemList[index]);
                                                                      }
```